# conflict between 2 ajax.googlepis code

Tags: jquery, ajax, slider, conflict

Here is my heads jquery links. I am using jquery 1.4.2 for my slider and 1.9.1 for mobile nav menu. I need both to run in my website. Please suggest how i can run both jquery without any conflict.

```
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
      animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-4', classout : 'dl-animate-out-4' }
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#myController").jFlow({
    slides: "#mySlides",
    width: "1000px",
    height: "335px",
    duration: 400
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance.. !

Comment: Already answered in another [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page). It can be done, news to me!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq191 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq142('#myController').jFlow({ /* etc... */ });
</script>
```